# Question about modify Vanitygen

Tags: development, wallet-recovery, vanitygen

I follow the instruction on this [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83309/modify-vanitygen-to-generate-from-massive-amount-of-given-private-key/) to create bitcoin address from given hex private key

In vanitygen.c
Replace

```
EC_KEY_generate_key(pkey);
```

with

```
  BIGNUM *res;
        BN_init(&start);
        res = &start;
        BN_hex2bn(&res, "3B1BCC5A67F38853810972B1DA8A67148FAD78C6CD6F22B2C823D141BE59C81C"); //Set up hex private key
        vg_set_privkey(res, pkey);
```

& remove case

```
if (++npoints >= rekey_at){}else{}
```

The input key will be replace with hashcat feature like this

```
"?1?1?1?1?1?1?1"+"A67F38853810972B1DA8A67148FAD78C6CD6F22B2C823D141BE59C81C"
```

I test it with single key first & notice the function still multiply the key which give a slightly different private key from the original & use my restore function, it only generate few hundreds actual private key & multiply the rest. No matter how i edit the "ptarraysize" value, it doesn't make CPU run on 100% power. Is anybody know to how to adjust the code to check address from mutiple generated key without multiply it. If possible, the performance will stay around like original vanitygen code or at least decline to 1-20 times, i wouldn't mind that. Thank You